# Center nav with Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I tried to center my navbar but when i use layout-align='space-between center' it isn't taking 100% width, and it is behaving like an inline element.

I am following the documentation but nothing works... here's the code:

```
<body ng-app="PetApp" layout='row'>

<div layout="row" flex>
  <md-nav-bar layout-fill aria-label='Main Menu' md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref='#inicio' name="inicio">Inicio</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#conheca" name="conheca">O Aplicativo</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#cadastro" name='cadastro'>Cadastre-se</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#contato" name='contato'>Contato</md-nav-item>
  </md-nav-bar>
</div>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('PetApp', ['ngMaterial']);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center md-navbar use layout options

```
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center" flex="70">
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Aq1d0RCiHYxVygSQ0zk?p=preview)

Comment: I tried and it centered, but it lost the 100% width as you can see: 

http://imgur.com/7iMpViU

Comment: Read about the layout options on ng-material documentation. Mark as answer if it has helped